# Panning issue when zooming with scrollviewer in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, msdn

I'm working on a flipview to recreate something **exactly like  photos app.**
I'm facing problem when restricting the scroll area(pan area) like I would not like the user to zoom/scroll in the dark area where the image is not present. I can do this by inserting a stackpanel but have to specify its height and width as the width of the image. But I'm not able to set this as I can't get the proper height,width details of the image.

Code:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="theScrollViewer" 
ViewChanged="theScrollViewer_ViewChanged"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" MaxZoomFactor="2" 
SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Image x:Name="theImage"
                       Stretch="Uniform" Source="Assets/2222.png"  />
     </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Can anyone help me out here how to exactly do this? 
Or any alternatives.

Edit:
Its not helping to set the stackpanel height and width dynamically to the scaled version of the image height & width got by **ImageProperties** . Is there any alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer (not so perfect though) thanks to [this](http://igrali.com/2015/07/16/why-is-my-zoomable-scrollviewer-snapping-the-image-to-the-left/) blog.

The main problems I faced were:
When we dont make

```
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

in this scrollviewer we get a snapping to left unwanted effect and when we do this by default we get a larger image and the image is not uniform.
This is solved with the help of the blog by setting the Flipview(parent) maxheight and maxwidth as the device height width with a converter. Still you will face a problem when changing the orientation so that is taken care of onWindowSize event handler to reset the maxheight and width of the Flipview.(Though note this is not a smooth answer).